# Populating datagrid from selected items in a combobox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I am trying to insert data from a **ComboBox** into a **DataGrid**.

Now with this code snippet below I can already insert a row into my datagrid, but the row is showing completely empty for some reason.

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (DataEntities DE = new DataEntities())
    {
        tblExtra E = (tblExtra)cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;
        List<string> items = new List<string> { E.ItemCode };

        items.Where(item => item.ToString() != null).ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            dgAddExtras.Items.Add(i);
        });
    }
}
```

I have also tried binding my columns through XAML, but it's with the same issue, it's still showing an empty line in my datagrid.

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemID}" Header="id" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" Header="Code" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemDescription}" Header="Description" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemPrice}" Header="Price" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemSellingPrice}" Header="QTY" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="100"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The Column names I gave the class are exactly the same as the Column names in my table, just in case someone wants to know.

I have no idea why it is doing this. It might be something very simple that I am missing, if so, sorry :P and thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong:

In below line you are adding just a `string` in the `List` '`items`'

```
List<string> items = new List<string> { E.ItemCode.ToString() };
```

So how can you expect a string will have all such properties which you are refereeing in your `DataGrid` columns?

Write it like this:

```
private void cmbAddExtras_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (DataEntities DE = new DataEntities())
    {
        tblExtra E = (tblExtra)cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem;
        List<tblExtra> items = new List<tblExtra> { E };

        items.Where(item => item != null).ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            dgAddExtras.Items.Add(i);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nitin! Thank you for your comment. I changed it like you said `List<string> items = new List<string> { E };` But where the "E" is it is giving me this error _The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments_. I also added **ToString** to the E, but the datagrid is stil showing empty lines?

Comment: Ohh yes, create `List<tblExtra>` instead of `List<string>` and then add E to that list.